# My QML file changes are ignored when I run my application

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have a `main.qml` file in my `main.qrc` resource file.
Sometimes, when I run my project, visible changes to my QML file appear in my program. Sometimes the same kind of changes do not appear, as if the modified QML file was not incorporated in the executable, and the old QML file was used instead.

I have checked that the file is correctly set as a dependency to `main.cpp` in the `Makefile`, therefore it is not [QTBUG-13334](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-13334)
I see that I'm not the only one suffering from this problem, for instance in [QTCREATORBUG-1627](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-1627).

What's happening ?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running your project with the wrong command.

There are two run commands in Qt Creator.
The main one, "Run", associated to `CTRL+R` keyboard shortcut, is located near the kit selector.

[image: Large Run icon]

The second one, "Re-run this run-configuration", with no shortcut, is located in the "Application Output" Toolbar.

[image: Application toolbar with Re-run icon]

So, if you're running your application with "Run" the first time you edit your QML file, and then try to fix some typos in your QML by clicking on the "Re-run this run-configuration" icon, latest changes won't appear.

The problem is that the "Run" icon (see Build menu) is used to display the "Re-run this run-configuration" command button.

[image: Run small icon]